# Select_tag doesn't update visually when a value is selected Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a difficulty with forms in rails. My form doesn't update visually when a value is selected. I am using the auto submit on change. How can I fix that? Also how can I set a default value for the select_tag?

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_tag({}, {:method => :get}) do %>
   <%= select_tag :selectedCurrency, options_for_select([['USD','usd_balance'],['EURO','euro_balance'],['YUAN','yuan_balance'],['GBP','gbp_balance']]), :onchange =>   "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'your form does not update visually'? What do you want to do after the value is selected? As for the default value you can do  `<%= select_tag :selectedCurrency, options_for_select([['USD','usd_balance'],['EURO','euro_balance'],['YUAN','yuan_balance'],['GBP','gbp_balance']], default_selected), :onchange =>   "this.form.submit();" %>`

Comment: If you mean when your form is submitted first time and afte page is reloaded you should be seeing the selected value instead of default value ? 
In that case for while passing options for select use following 
`options_for_select([['USD','usd_balance'],['EURO','euro_balance'],['YUAN','yuan_balance'],['GBP','gbp_balance']], (params[:selectedCurrency] || default_value) )`